# Java server socket deployment on EC2 instance. Client socket connection timeout

Tags: java, sockets, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

I face a timeout when trying to connect from my java websocket client to my websocket server that is deployed in a EC2 instance.

The connection works fine in my local machine and the security group allows all TCP incoming traffic.

My assumption it is that there's a networking step I'm missing.

**Steps I followed to deploy my server socket on EC2:**

- Launch EC2 instance (Amazon Linux)
- Install java and maven
- Exec command mvn clean -X and mvn install
- Exec command java -jar mywebserver.jar

--> result: The code is running in port xxx

**Server socket creation:**

```
    try {


        s = new ServerSocket(port); //listen on specified port

        Log.add("Port " + port + " address: " + s.getInetAddress() + ": server started");


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.add("Server error " + ex + "(port " + port + ")");
        throw new Exception("Error "+ex);
    }
```

**Client web**

```
public Client(String serverIp, int serverPort) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    s = new Socket(serverIp, serverPort);
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Felix

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest :

- Double-check firewall settings
- try to ping/telnet server machine from client etc..
- Use InetAddress in your Socket
  initialization on client code as you could also use its isReachable()
  method

I think you're also missing the below part on server side :

```
Socket socket = s.accept();
```

Please see some client/server socket examples, eg :
https://www.journaldev.com/741/java-socket-programming-server-client

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

 * Firewalls should be ok as I could connect via SSH to my EC2 instance.
 * Also I tried by creating the server using InetAddress

Comment: Added in answer the `s.accept()` part that you may be missing on server side